# Can you change text or images based on the window.location method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have 3 servers that look like this:

```
https://server-1.com
https://server-2.com
https://server-3.com
```

Inside of my Vue app I would like to switch out an image dependent upon the server that i'm on. Can I use something like

```
v-bind:src="server1.image"
```

to access an image?

What i'm thinking is Vue would look something like:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    server1: { 
              image1: imagelocation
              image2: imagelocation 
             },
    server2: { 
              image1: imagelocation
              image2: imagelocation 
             },
    server3: { 
              image1: imagelocation
              image2: imagelocation 
             }

});
```

Is this possible? Am I using Vue incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make `server` a computed property: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example

you can set the value of server based on whatever you want inside the function.

Comment: I'll look into this now.